# Group show/hide image elements using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, gallery, show-hide

How to make sub galleries in a gallery script (exmpl. unitegallery) and show/hide elements on link click using javascript? Group bunch of elements together to form several subgalleries and then show/hide.

Answer (score 1):

Its actually very simple. All you have to do is pass the group of the item in the gallery to a show/hide function as below. In the example below each item in gallery has 2 main classes first is the shared class by each item `gallery` and the 2nd class is the gallery group. If you want to show every item in gallery then pass the shared class or if you want to show one group then pass the group class

```js
function showGallery(group){
  // get all items in the gallery
  var allItems = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery");
  
  // loop through each item
  allItems.forEach((item) => {
    
    // remove show class to make it hide
    item.classList.remove("show");
    
    // if the item has the class that is sent to the function then show
    if(item.classList.contains(group)){
      // add show class if group match 
      item.classList.add("show");
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.gallery{
  display: none;
}
.gallery.show{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery car show">Car 1</div>
<div class="gallery house show">House 1</div>
<div class="gallery car show">Car 2</div>

<button onclick="showGallery('gallery')">All</button>
<button onclick="showGallery('car')">Car</button>
<button onclick="showGallery('house')">House</button>
```

Comment: Could you explain more what do you  mean by "gallery script overrides styles". Do you mean you can not write styles or when you write styles it does not take effect because of gallery script? Is gallery script a public library and if could you put the link to it? If you could update your question with these and also related codes you have would help us in assisting you